# How to display the Chakra UI 'Alert'?

Tags: javascript, promise, chakra-ui

I'm trying to display the Alert message using Chakra Ui but it's not displaying. Please help.

```
.catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorMessage, errorCode);
            <Alert status='error'>
                <AlertIcon />
                <AlertTitle>Error!</AlertTitle>
                <AlertDescription>Email/ Password Did Not Matched.</AlertDescription>
            </Alert>
        });
```

Comment: You have to return it. `return ( alert jsx... )`

Comment: I tried using it as you suggested but it's not displaying (visual representation) properly as the ChakraUI mentioned, it's simply displaying an 'alert-box'. (screenshot attached).

I tried this code:-

return (alert(
                    <Alert status='error'>
                    <AlertIcon />
                    <AlertTitle>Error!</AlertTitle>
                    <AlertDescription>Email/ Password Mismatch.</AlertDescription>
                </Alert>

Comment: It should be `return (<Alert status='error'> <AlertIcon /> <AlertTitle>Error!</AlertTitle> <AlertDescription>Email/ Password Did Not Matched.</AlertDescription> </Alert>)`, not wrapped in a alert function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components like `<Alert />` can't be added to the catch of a promise. You have to conditionally render the alert in the return statement of a component like so:

```js
function LoginExample() {
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false)

  const handleLogin = (email, password) => {
    loginUser(email, password)
      .then((res) => /* handle success */)
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage, errorCode);

        setShowAlert(true)
      })
  }

  return (
    <>
      {showAlert && (
        <Alert status='error'>
          <AlertIcon />
          <AlertTitle>Error!</AlertTitle>
          <AlertDescription>Email/ Password Did Not Matched.</AlertDescription>
        </Alert>
      )}

      {/* rest of jsx */}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't look like you have the OP a good solution.